# Total force on a wall with variable density fluid

Tags: fluid-statics

Say I have a fluid with a density given by $$\rho =\rho(y) = 3y+5 \; \left[\frac{kg}{m^3}\right]$$

Where y has origin at the fluid surface and is positive downward. Now I have a rectangular wall of width 4 and height 6 filled with and supporting the fluid. If I want to find the force exerted on the wall by the fluid, I am thinking I just integrate over the area to find the total pressure on the wall. As in

$$F = \int_0^6 \int_0^4 \rho(y)\cdot g \cdot y \;dx dy = 4g \;\int_0^6 3y^2+5y \; dy = 4\cdot g \cdot 306 = 1224g \left[\frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}\right] = 1224g \left[N\right]$$

The problem is that I was told this was the incorrect approach and that my solution was wrong.  I am wondering if I was supposed to calculate the center of pressure location and multiply this by total pressure instead, but it seems that this will result in the same solution.  I am looking for insight into how this should be thought of physically if my approach is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Check my work isn't really on topic here.  That said, your approach sounds like it makes sense.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect why I posted.  Hopefully it is clearer that this is more than a simple "check my work" post.

Comment: Sorry, but "Does anyone know where I went wrong?" is still basically the same thing.    I should have linked this the first time https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange  There's some advice here on how you could possibly make this conceptual and on-topic.

Comment: I agree, your integration is incorrect. Furthermore, I agree with @JMac that your question is a homework like question.

Comment: Homework questions are not disallowed, as per the link shared above. I have tried to make it more conceptual, and if I'm still falling short I am unsure how to do much more than I have done. It would be helpful to say where I went wrong conceptually rather than my integration is wrong. Do you mean that I performed the integration incorrectly?

Comment: I think it should be: $$ F(h) = A \int_0^h \rho(y) \cdot g \cdot y \space \textrm{d}y $$

Comment: Thanks, Agnius, but if I use that equation I get the wrong units: area * density * acceleration * meters * meters gives units of Newton meters.

Comment: Thanks Philip.  Yes, the total force on the wall is what is required.

Comment: Then rename question, because now there is part "... **at depth**", so total force or force at depth ?

Comment: Ah, ok.  I renamed the question.  Thanks Agnius.

Comment: In a previous comment (that I've deleted) I said that I could see nothing wrong. I wasn't looking! One integration is needed to find how pressure varies with depth (though other methods are possible); another integration is needed to find the force on the wall by integrating the depth-dependent pressure over the area of the wall. The method that Karlton uses is an incorrect attempt to do both in a single integration.

Comment: Philip, see the answer I posted before your latest comment.

Comment: Have done so, and commented on the new answer.

Comment: Jerks putting the question on hold even though it was changed to include a question about the physical concepts. And even though I found another way to conceptualize it myself and added that as an answer.  Power hungry much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of another way to conceptualize this, and I get a different answer.  This approach also makes sense, and I think it is more easily defensible.

To find the pressure at a depth of h, we need to find the weight of the fluid above h.  The average density of the fluid above a depth h must be equal to the integral:

$$\rho_{avg} = \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \rho(y) \cdot \; dy = \frac{3}{2}h + 5$$

The pressure at a depth h is the average density above depth h times the gravitational acceleration times the depth (h). So to find the total force, we integrate from zero depth to total depth:

$$\int_0^6 \int_0^4 \rho_{avg} \cdot g \cdot y\; dxdy = \int_0^6 \int_0^4 \left(\frac{3}{2}y + 5\right) \cdot g \cdot y\; dxdy = 792 g\left[ N \right]$$

Comment: Well done! My own preference would have been to calculate the pressure at depth $h$ as $$p(h)=g \int_0^h \rho (y) dy$$ and then to integrate this pressure wrt area over the area of the vertical wall. No need to bother with averages.

Comment: @PhilipWood, Indeed I also would choose such approach, it's more natural for me. I came to similar formula, just made an error including redundant term $y$. Sometimes choosing most suitable initial equation(s) is half-job :-)

Comment: I see that this is equivalent.  Thanks, both of you!